# Find a users karma on Reddit

Tags: python, xml, reddit

I'm trying to create an app that shows the viewer useful information about a target Reddit user. Everything has ran smoothly, until I realised that people would probably want to see the users karma.

In order to make it more fun and challenging for myself, I decided I wouldn't work with PRAW, the Python Reddit API Wrapper, but instead use urllib.request and xml.etree.ElementTree to manually parse the xml.

There is a problem, however. I have looked *everywhere* in the xml given (As an example, the user [reddit](http://www.reddit.com/user/reddit.xml)). On every page I've tried, both the link's and the user's karma is nowhere to be seen. Does anyone know a way to find this elusive karma?

I would love it if someone has a solution to my problem which does not include PRAW. Thank you!

Comment: @SalvadorDali: uhm, yes it is. This is not an unreasonable request, really.

Comment: @MartijnPieters so you mean that questions with no input should be asked here? Like: guys, I want this requirement. How to do this?

Comment: @Salvador: this is not a 'do my homework' request. I see some effort here, figuring out how remote APIS work is perfectly on topic.

Comment: @MartijnPieters still it shows no attempt from OP how to solve it. Just a statement what he wants and does not want.

Comment: @SalvadorDali sure it does; they found the user feed. You are being overly harsh here.

Answer (score 6):

You are looking at the user *feed*; that link only lists posts.

You want to parse the API instead; the [`/user/{username}/about.json` route](http://www.reddit.com/dev/api#GET_user_%7Busername%7D_about.json) contains the user Karma. So for user `reddit` the URL would be:

```
http://www.reddit.com/user/reddit/about.json
```

This returns *JSON*, not XML so you'd use the `json` library to parse this instead.